# bash expanding value of a variable to use in another variable

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

I hope the question makes sense, I would like to do something like:

```
a=test
b=a
echo ${$b} # should echo test
```

Basically I'd like `$b` to expand to the value `a` and have bash echo out the value of variable `$a` (since `${a}` is `test`).

What syntax should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a=test
b=a
echo ${!b} # does echo test
```

Comment: great, good to know dereferences work with vars ;) I only knew that syntax in bash arrays.

Comment: why don't you do it like this?:

a=test; b=$a; echo $b

Comment: @RaphaelRoth - because what you suggest is not indirection

Comment: A more portable alternative (but also quite dangerous if not used carefully) is `eval echo \$$b`.